# Shopware 6 EntitiyDefinition class name is null

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

What could be the reason for https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/trunk/src/Core/Framework/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/EntityCompilerPass.php#L48 to return null ? I have a service like

```xml
<service id=" MyPlugin\Core\Content\Bundle\MyCustomEntityDefinition">
      <tag name="shopware.entity.definition" entity="my_table" />
</service>
```

The class exists in the path as written in the service above and looks like

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPlugin\Core\Content\Bundle;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\PrimaryKey;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Required;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\IdField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\JsonField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;

class MyCustomEntityDefinition extends EntityDefinition {
  public const ENTITY_NAME = 'my_table';

  public function getEntityName(): string {
    return self::ENTITY_NAME;
  }

  public function getCollectionClass(): string {
    return MyCustomEntityCollection::class;
  }

  public function getEntityClass(): string {
    return MyCustomEntity::class;
  }

  protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection {
    return new FieldCollection([
      (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
      new JsonField('my_field', 'my_field'),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Also the thrown error Class name must be a valid object or a string  doesn't help at all when encountering this, maybe I should create an issue for better error handling for it?

Checking the Shopware core code the inherited class `EntityDefinition` has the method

```php
/**
 * @return class-string<EntityDefinition>
*/
final public function getClass(): string {
    return static::class;
}
```

Which is the one returning `null`

Comment: Just a wild guess ...the leading whitespace in your service definition ID  `service id=" MyPlugin` ???